# CocoaPods setup taking forever

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

Trying to set up the pod, but it seems to be taking forever.

Steps

> $ sudo gem install cocoapods
> 1 gem installed

> $ pod setup
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:212: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777 Setting up CocoaPods master repo
> ...

Is there a problem with access to the repository? I saw that there is a current problem with the broken specs repo (https://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/), but that should not affect new installs, i.e. pod setup right?

Comment: Seems to be working now.

Comment: CocoaPods always have been taking a very long time to install.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to speed up what you can do the following:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods --no-document -V
```

It skips out on the documentation, and installs verbosely so you can see what is happening.